# Quick updates for ios phonegap hybrid apps

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

Apple doesn't allow remote code, but I've heard many people say that hybrid apps can be quickly updated without going through apple approval. How is this done? How much "remote code" is acceptable for apple?

My stack is phonegap and angularjs.

Comment: there is no data about this, it's more like, will you risk to get your app deleted if apple finds out that you update the code remotely?

Comment: Didn't facebook publically give tech talks about remotely updating their hybrid apps? It didn't sound like they got deleted or anything.

Comment: Can you provide any link about the facebook tech talks? I didn't hear anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the following is roughly how Apple seems to see it:

- If you are downloading *content* that has some JavaScript code along with it (say, to support event binding, etc.), there is no problem. It's *part* of the content (even if code).
- If you are downloading *code* that changes the *core functionality* of your app, Apple *may* take issue. (Just because they don't always do so doesn't mean a particular reviewer might not take issue with you for doing so.)

The extreme example, of course, would be to develop a Calculator app, and then via a code update (routed around Apple's review process) change the app to a Minecraft clone. Obvious problems, there, right? There are plenty of avenues here for abuse (intentional or not).

To be honest, although your update probably wouldn't change the behavior of your app completely, it is risky in order to perform these kinds of updates. Given that Apple can't watch every app with an eagle eye, you'd probably squeak through. But is it worth the *chance* that you won't? Only you can answer that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using HTML5's cache manifest. No issues on iOS submission/terms from what I have experienced. Really need to evaluate your use case though, as UX can suffer.